# Hide "Add Relationship" Button

Tags: relationships

I would like to remove the "Add Relationship" button from the Relationship tab. I've been auditing some of the data and noticed that my users have been adding and removing relationships from this page. This caused a couple of data issues because the relationships are not connected to the cases. Then relationships were duplicating.

Anyway, I tried removing the "Add Relationships" button via css. The actions-link css, however, affects other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what CMS you're using - it would be nice if you could permission this but I can't in WordPress so I see the need you have.

Just add the parent selector as well:

.contact-summary-relationship-tab .action-link
(the parent id an ID not a class but when I place the pound sign it thinks it's formatting)

Keep in mind, there is still an option in the actions menu as well that you'll want to hide.

Comment: Which file do you use to add the CSS? It didn't work for civicrm.css. Edited to add: I'm using Drupal.

Comment: To override civi styles, rather than edit the core civicrm.css you should employ an 'override' css file. You can set the URL here: Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs > Custom CSS URL: URL to use a custom CSS file. Also, the parent I referenced should be #contact-summary-relationship-tab